# RemoteFilter on ContinuousQuery .NET to Java

Tags: ignite

I have a .NET client node, and several Java server nodes. There are no .NET server nodes. I have one cache, and in that cache there are many different types. I think of a cache instance as a schema, not a single table. From .NET I want to subscribe to grid events. However, depending on what the client is doing we may only be interested in a subset of types or object instances. Right now, I need to subscribe to all events and then do my filtering on object type (and instance fields) on the .NET client side. What I really want to do is filter on the remote Java side. So a ContinuousQuery with a RemoteFilter seems perfect, although from here, https://apacheignite-net.readme.io/docs/platform-interoperability we see it is not supported.Is there any way I can achieve some server side filtering, at least on the type itself? It doesn't seem right to create one cache per type in order to achieve this.

Thanks!

Gordon.

Answer (score 1):

Remote filter is supported for continuous queries. However, if you're querying on .NET client and filter is implemented in .NET language, server nodes nodes must be running with .NET runtime as well. Refer to this page for information about how to start standalone .NET node: https://apacheignite-net.readme.io/docs/getting-started-2

Comment: All servers are Java, only the client is .NET. Is there some way to implement the RemoteFilter in Java, and then reference it from the .NET side? Obviously the filter gets executed on the remote Java side, but I need someway to specify that on the .NET client side when I start the query.

Comment: No, there is no way to do such mixed query. Why not start .NET servers? Note that .NET server doesn't mean that you can't run Java there. Nothing will break for other clients that use only Java (if this is the case).

Comment: Our environment is windows clients and linux servers. We use .NET on the front because it generally supports a much richer desktop experience, which is important for our application. So we have only .NET clients, and only Java servers. It would be great if we could reference the name of a RemoteFilter from the .NET side that was implemented and executed on the Java side.